# Select image from gallery and upload to data storage on my computer/server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have managed to make an app that selects picture and uploads to Firebase storage, but what I need is select/capture (doesn't matter for now) and upload it to my compture storage. Also would be perfect if I could give a name.

My upload code and attaching android studio project.

DropBox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqt3dpz7gw4ucvv/Nuotraukos.rar?dl=0

```
   public void UploadImageToFirebase() {

    if (FilePathUri != null) {
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading");
        StorageReference storageRef = storageReference.child(Storage_Path + System.currentTimeMillis() +
         "." + GetFileExtension(FilePathUri));

        storageRef.putFile(FilePathUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        String TempName = ImageName.getText().toString().trim();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploaded",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                                ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo = new ImageUploadInfo(TempName,
                                taskSnapshot.toString());

                        String ImageUploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                        databaseReference.child(ImageUploadId).setValue(imageUploadInfo);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "my own storage"? The code you are using is from the Firebase SDK (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/package-summary) and, as such, you will not be able to use it to store a file in another platform. You can only use this code together with a Firebase Storage back-end.

Comment: I mean that I need to upload from app to my computer

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure to understand :-) Do you mean on your own PC/laptop? On a server where you would store the file? What is your exact need from a user requirement perspective?

Comment: Yes computer and server. User will be uploading pictures and certain people will view those pictures and fix problem in it. All that app has to do is snap a picture and upload to private storage in this case my computer or server

Comment: To upload to your PC/Server it would require to have a FTP server (or other type of server to upload the file) and then just use your app to upload to the that server. At least it is what I'm understanding from your question.

Also remenber to use AsyncTask for the upload, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: If you are using Firebase you can only upload *to the Firebase server*. Firebase doesn't offer private servers.

Comment: I was wondering, is it possible to make camera api that takes picture, shows it in imageview, uploads it to my shown location and doesn't save it on the phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this and it is working for now.

```
private void UploadImage (){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UploadUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String Response = jsonObject.getString("response");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,Response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mImageView.setImageResource(0);
                        mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mEditText.setText("");
                        mEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    })


    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("name",mEditText.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("image",ImageToString(bitmap));

            return params;
        }
    };

    SingletonClass.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);

}

private String ImageToString(Bitmap bitmap){

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte [] imgBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    return Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```